# How to architect ASP.Net app to load Controller specific JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an asp.net app with a site.js which is getting lengthy. What is the proper way to architect the file structure so that /home routes will load a home.js file and /product routes will load a routes.js file?

Ideally I would like to keep all the js files in the wwwroot folder and not next to the views or within them so I can minify them with the compiler

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an extension method for Html helper and call that on `_Layout.cshtml` as `@Html.RenderControllerJs(Url);` so that it gets called every time and inject the respective js.

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtentions
{
    public static IHtmlContent RenderControllerJs(this HtmlHelper html, UrlHelper urlHelper)
    {
        var env = html.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IHostEnvironment>();

        var controllerName = html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString().ToString();
        var jsFileRelativePath = Path.Combine("<folder_path_for_all_controller_js>", $"{controllerName}.js");
        var controllerJsFilePath = Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, jsFileRelativePath);
        if (File.Exists(controllerJsFilePath))
        {
            return html.Raw(
                $"<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"{urlHelper.Content(Path.Combine("~", jsFileRelativePath))}\"></script>");
        }

        return new HtmlString("");
    }
}
```

You can also write custom logic specific to any controller. You have full control now.